# change iis .net framework version using cmd

Tags: iis, frameworks

I want to change iis .net framework version using command line in windows 7. I have tred following solution but it doesn't work

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config /section:system.applicationHost/applicationPools /applicationPoolDefaults.managedRuntimeVersion:"v4.0" /commit:apphost
```

Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: Iterate all application pools and then change the framework version for each pools you want. The one above only affects new pools after your change.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution

```
appcmd set apppool /apppool.name: DefaultAppPool /managedRuntimeVersion:v4.0
```

thanks for sharing your answer

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to run below command to modify the Machine/WebRoot/APPHOST's clr version.

```
appcmd.exe set config  -section:applicationPools /applicationPoolDefaults.managedRuntimeVersion:"v4.0"
```

Result:

[image]